# Swift ios: drag view controller onto screen

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any way to drag a view controller onto the current view controller using Swift? I would like to drag from the bottom of the screen and have the new view controller follow the finger. When the finger releases, I want for the view to snap into place. The view controller that I plan to drag on needs to have a transparent background so that the previous view is still visible. I tried using a swipe gesture paired with an animation that brings in the view from the bottom, but the previous view turns black momentarily before the animation is complete. Also, it doesn't follow the finger's path. This is similar to what happens when you try drag from the bottom of the camera app. It brings up a page, following your finger, and darkening the background. I am doing this programmatically. Thanks.

Comment: you need to implement something like [this](https://github.com/ostatnicky/DraggableViewController)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you will need to use a `UIPageViewController` and set its transition style to scroll and navigation to vertical. There are lot's of great tutorials on how to use a `UIPageViewController` so just look online.